# Wordpress programatically inserted post not showing in authors profile

Tags: posts

I have inserted a post programmatically in a wordpress
When viewing the post on the authors' page, there is no post from the post that I have inserted programmatically, but when manually updating the post, it's then working and showing properly. What will the cause and how to solve this any guide?

Code in my plugin:

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_insert_data_to_post_type_func', 'insert_data_to_post_type_func');

function insert_data_to_post_type_func(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ebay_listings';
    $select_query =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name LIMIT 1");
    $user_id_get = $_POST['userID'];
    foreach ($select_query as $sq) {
        
        $heading = $sq->title;
        $x = json_decode($heading);

        $des = $sq->long_desctiption;
        $y = json_decode($des);
        $z = json_decode($sq->add_id);
        $imgs = json_decode($sq->image_URL);
        $date = json_decode($sq->date);
        $location = json_decode($sq->location);
        $list_items = json_decode($sq->list_items);
        $price = json_decode($sq->price);

        foreach ($x as $tx) {
            $title[] = $tx;
        }
        foreach ($y as $lng_des) {
            $description[] = $lng_des;
        }

        foreach ($z as $add) {
            $add_id[] = $add;
        }
        foreach ($date as $dt) {
            $eb_date[] = $dt;
        }
        foreach ($location as $loc) {
            $locality[] = $loc;
        }
        foreach ($list_items as $lit) {
            $listings[] = $lit;
        }
        foreach ($price as $p) {
            $pricing[] = $p;
        }
        $i = -1;
      
        foreach ($imgs as $sd) {
          
            $i++;
            $image_name = basename($sd);
           
            $advert_posts = array(
                'post_author' => $user_id_get,
                'post_type' => 'advert',
                'post_title' => $title[$i],
                'post_content' => $description[$i] . $listings[$i],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($advert_posts);
            $category_id = 877;
            $taxonomy = 'advert-category';
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array( $category_id ), $taxonomy , true );
            add_post_meta( $post_id , 'advert_sale_price' , $pricing[$i]);
            add_post_meta( $post_id , 'advert_type' , 1);
            add_post_meta( $post_id , 'advert_negotiable' , 1);
            add_post_meta( $post_id , 'advert_location' , $locality[$i]);
            
            var_dump( get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ), $user_id_get);
            
            $upload = wp_upload_bits($image_name, null, file_get_contents($sd, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH));
            $imageFile = $upload['file'];
            $wpFileType = wp_check_filetype($imageFile, null);
          
            // rwmb_set_meta( $post_id, 'advert_gallery', $imageFile, $args = [] );
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $wpFileType['type'],  // file type
                'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($imageFile),  // sanitize and use image name as file name
                'post_content' => '',  // could use the image description here as the content
                'post_status' => 'inherit'
            );
            $attachmentId = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $imageFile, $post_id);

            // insert and return attachment metadata
            $attachmentData = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachmentId, $imageFile);

            // update and return attachment metadata
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachmentId, $attachmentData);
            // finally, associate attachment id to post id
            $success = set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachmentId);
            add_post_meta( $post_id , 'advert_gallery' , set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachmentId));
            
            if ($success) {
                echo 'Data and images have been inserted';
            } else {
                echo 'Something went wrong';
            }
        }
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you defining the `$user_id_get` - where's the code for that? And where does your plugin code run - what page (an admin page?) and is the code in a function hooked on any hook - if so, what hook is it?

Comment: Actually, it's a form submission that gets the user id of the marked user. 
I am not using any hook. It' running on ajax form submit. @SallyCJ

Comment: How does the submission work - does the form, via AJAX, submit to the same page, a custom PHP file like `example.com/process.php`, or the `admin-ajax.php` file? And I suspected that the post author isn't being set, so try `var_dump( get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ), $user_id_get );` right after the call to `wp_insert_post()`. What's the dump output?

Comment: Form is submiting via wp-ajax.php and post is assigned to the author properly cause I have tracked each users post . via get_userdata(user_id). and it has the same post that I assigned to that user.

Comment: "post is assigned to the author properly" - are you sure it's assigned to the `$user_id_get`? Can you just do the `var_dump()` and see what it outputs? And if the values are good, then maybe you should try deactivating plugins and/or switching to a default theme (e.g. 2021), and see if that helps.

Comment: I ran var dump() and it correctly displays the user id, but I tried deactivating plugins and switching themes and still couldn't find anything.

Comment: When you said "authors' page", you did mean the default "author" pages like `example.com/author/admin`, right? Also, have you considered using the REST API instead? (To create the CPT post) And you said "Form is submiting via wp-ajax.php", but what is wp-ajax.php? Did you mean the `wp_ajax_` hook? If so, can you show your full callback code?

Comment: Yes I have edited the code above please check.

Comment: Actually, the issue is post is not inserted in the database until I manually click the update button on the post edit screen.

Comment: Well, I'm getting confused now.. but what I can suggest is, enable `WP_Error`, i.e. set the 2nd parameter for `wp_insert_post()` to `true` - `$post_id = wp_insert_post($advert_posts, true);` - and then right below/after that, do something like `if ( is_wp_error( $post_id ) ) { echo 'post not created: ' . $post_id->get_error_message(); continue; }`. That will help you confirm whether the post is being successfully inserted to the database or not. Also note that CPTs are by default not included in the main query on "author" pages, but I guessed you already got that handled?

Comment: And where is the form in question - is it on the post editing screen or a custom admin page? How are you adding the form (what hooks used, if any), or were you actually referring to the post editing form - and if so, is this the classic editor or the block/Gutenberg editor? And how is the AJAX triggered - automatically (in the background) or via a button click, or?

Comment: Issue resolved there is metabox field which is mandatory filled in order add post in the database.